# Passing Data through multiple View Controllers with segue [Swift 3.0 Xcode]

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, prepared-statement, segue

[image]

NOTE: Question has been edited in an attempt to be more clear with my issue.

Hey, I am trying to pass data through multiple VCS. I want to pass data (arrays) from V2 -> V3 and then V3 -> V1 but I want to be able to only navigate through the VCs as such: V1 - V2 - V3 and V3 - V2 - V1.
So what I need to learn is how to pass data without navigating to a different VC as well as setting up two preparetosegue methods to pass data between V2 -> V3 and V3 -> V1 while also being able to navigate between all VCs. When I create my first preparetosegue, I am unable to use other segues associated in my VC to navigate to other VCs without getting a Fatal Error.
Can anyone help me?
Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Heres my attempt:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var name = String()
var StopButInfo = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }


}


  import UIKit

  class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  var StringArray = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBOutlet var PHeight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var PName: UITextField!



@IBAction func Search(_ sender: Any) {
    if PHeight.text != ""{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SearchSegue", sender: self)}
    let CDstart = String(describing: Date())
    StringArray.append(CDstart)
    StringArray.append(PName.text!)
    StringArray.append(PHeight.text!)
    }




override func prepare(for SearchSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    let thirdController = SearchSegue.destination as! ThirdViewController
    thirdController.SearchButInfo = StringArray
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }


   }

 import UIKit

 class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
var height = String()
var SearchButInfo = [String]()

var StringArray = [String]()



@IBAction func Stop(_ sender: Any) {
    if StringArray.count != 0{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToStart", sender: self)
    }
    let CDStop = String(describing: Date())
    StringArray.append(CDStop)
    StringArray.append(height)
}





override func prepare(for SegueToStart: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    let firstController = SegueToStart.destination as! ViewController
    firstController.StopButInfo = StringArray}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting and  on which line of code? Can you post the line of code that breaks please? And also the error message

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on line `let secondController = segueMVH.destination as! ThirdViewController` with error message "Could not cast value of type 'HC.ViewController' (0x107b33ec0) to 'HC.ThirdViewController' (0x107b33f48)."

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which view controller's segue is about to be performed, this can be done like this inside `prepare(for segueMVH: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method:

```
if let firstController = segueMVH.destination as! FirstViewController {
    // Set first view controller's data

} else if let secondController = segueMVH.destination as! SecondViewController {
    // Set second view controller's data

} else if let thirdController = segueMVH.destination as! ThirdViewController {
    // Set third view controller's data
}
```

Note: It's better to use a different identifier for each segue to be able to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

The error you got on `let secondController = segueMVH.destination as! ThirdViewController` is saying that you are casing `HC.ViewController` into `ThirdViewController` and that's why it failed. It means that the destination view controller of your segue is not `ThirdViewController`.

To further help you understand segue: A segue is a connection between a source view controller and a destination view controller and can be only used between them two. See this picture:
[image]
In this case, I have a segue connection in my storyboard connected between my VC1's button and VC2. In this case, my button click will trigger this segue and `prepare(for segue)` method can only be in VC1 where it passes data to VC2.

So in your situation, you believe that the destination of your segue is `ThirdViewController` but it's actually not. So please check your segue with identifier `segueMVH` to see if it is connected between your current view controller and your `ThirdViewController`.

Hope this helps